# Search array of filenames for file ending with ".txt"

Tags: php, arrays, filenames, ends-with

I have an array with filenames.

I want to check if the array have a file with extension '.txt'.

How can I do that?

`in_array` only checks for a specific value.

Comment: `array_filter` and strstr callback for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$iHaz = FALSE;

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (preg_match('/\.txt$/', $item)) {
        $iHaz = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
```

Contrarily to other answers suggesting `array_filter`, I don't return something. I just check if it exists in the array. Besides, this implementation is more efficient than `array_filter` because it breaks out of the loop once it's found something.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter). In the callback, check for the presence of the `.txt` extension.

If the result  of `array_filter` has entries (is truthy), then you can get the first one or all of them. If the array is empty, there were no matches.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the items in your array, and then perform either a regular expression or a strpos match on each item. Once you find a match, you can return true.

With `strpos()`:

```
$array = array('one.php', 'two.txt');

$match = false;
foreach ($array as $filename) {
    if (strpos($filename, '.txt') !== FALSE) {
        $match = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

With regex:

```
$array = array('one.php', 'two.txt');

$match = false;
foreach ($array as $filename) {
    if (preg_match('/\.txt$/', $filename)) {
        $match = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Both will result in `$match` equating to `true`.

Comment: `substr` -> I think you mean `strpos`.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$files = array('foo.txt', 'bar.txt', 'nope.php', ...);

$txtFiles = array_filter($files, function ($item) {
    return '.txt' === substr($item, -4); // assuming that your string ends with '.txt' otherwise you need something like strpos or preg_match
});

var_dump($txtFiles); // >> Array ( [0] => 'foo.txt', [1] => 'bar.txt' )
```

The [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter) function loops through the array and passes the value into a callback.  If the callback returns true, it will keep the value, otherwise it will remove the value from the array. After all items are passed in the callback, the result array is returned.

---

Oh, you just want to know if `.txt` is in the array. Some other suggestions:

```php
$match = false;

array_map(function ($item) use ($match) {
    if ('.txt' === substr($match, -4)) {
        $match = true;
    }
}, $filesArray);
```

```php
$match = false;
if (false === strpos(implode(' ', $filesArray), '.txt')) {
    $match = true;
}
```

Comment: @danronmoon thank you, I just edited it. (at first I thought I will solve the problem with `array_map` which has the `callback, input` order...)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with files you should use `array_filter` and `pathinfo`

```
$files = array_filter(array("a.php","b.txt","z.ftxt"), function ($item) {
    return pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === "txt";
});

var_dump($files); // b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter your array results based on the file extension using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
// Our array to be filtered
$files = array("puppies.txt", "kittens.pdf", "turtles.txt");

// array_filter takes an array, and a callable function
$result = array_filter($files, function ($value) {
    // Function is called once per array value
    // Return true to keep item, false to filter out of results
    return preg_match("/\.txt$/", $value);
});

// Output filtered values
var_dump($result);
```

Which results in the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(11) "puppies.txt"
  [2]=> string(11) "turtles.txt"
}
```

Execute it: http://goo.gl/F3oJr

Answer (score 0):

If you want a filtered array containing only strings ending in `.txt`, then PHP8 has a native function for you.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VVCkl))

```
$array = ['one.php', 'two.txt'];

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($v) => str_ends_with($v, '.txt')
    )
);
```

If you want a true/false result and don't need to iterate the whole array, then conditionally `break` the loop. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ngLtN))

```
$found = false;
foreach ($array as $filename) {
    if (str_ends_with($filename, '.txt')) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
var_export($found);
```